# CKEditor within Swing based browser double ENTER problem

Tags: swing, ckeditor

Background:

To add some basic HTML/rich text editing to our application that is compatible with our web interface I am attempting to embedded CKEditor within the swing based webrenderer browser. Webrenderer acts like a swing component and then loads up my simple HTML page containing an invocation to start CKEditor.

This works fine and I am able to set/get the edited HTML text within my application.

Problem:

The issue I'm seeing is that whenever the ENTER key is hit it is as if it is processed twice. E.g each press of the ENTER key generates 2 lines in the edited text. Or if typing in a bullet list then a press of ENTER causes the list to terminate an text entry to start on a fresh line below (same behaviour as if you hit ENTER twice in a normal browser).

If I switch CKEditor to source mode or if I use a basic HTML textarea then ENTER behaves normally. Also if I load my simple editor page into firefox directly then it works fine.

I guess some interaction is occuring between CKEditor and the swing browser. (I've recently noticed that if the browser is used inside a JDialog with default button then any hit of ENTER activates the default button, so not sure where the handling of ENTER is between swing and webrenderer)

Thanks,
Rob.

Answer (score 0):

May Be Useful [CKEditor Tutorial](http://netbeans.dzone.com/nb-ckeditor-javamail-tutorial)

Comment: Whilst your answer may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the article in an answer below, and provide the link for reference